# What is the best way to have a cumulative variable in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a list view that takes a query set and shows it in a table...  I want to have a column that is the cumulative value of one of the other columns (model field)

Example:

```
DATE      |DESC   |DURATION  |CUMULATIVE
2013-01-01|Meeting|5 minutes |5 minutes
2013-01-03|Diner  |3 minutes |8 minutes
2013-01-07|Break  |10 minutes|18 minutes
2013-01-10|Call   |1 minutes |19 minutes
```

since django templates can't have code in it.. how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not accumulating the value in views?

Comment: Yeah well I guess it's one way, thats what im wondering... whats the best way? if I do it in the view, how should I go about doing this so that it's obvious from the template

Comment: I believe it's really would be better to place this logic to view. You will end up writing a really ugly context processor or kind of. Also, Django philosophy is all about removing as many logic from template as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to just loop the queryset in the view, keeping track of the cumulative, and add the cumulative var to the objects:

```
cumulative = 0
for item in queryset:
    cumulative += item.minutes
    item.cumulative = cumulative
```

Then you can access it in the template like `{{ item.cumulative }}`

Comment: Ahhh yes this seems very simple, I guess im too used to Java that you cannot add properties to instances on the fly like that!